# Why Sometime The Ajax Request Respond Internal Server Error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, jquery-ajaxq

As I already mentioned in title **sometime** the ajax request respond internal server error.
I am working on an application i which a send a lot of ajax requests, some requests are sent after regular interval of time by using **setInterval** and **setTimeout** functions. On the other hand, some requests depend upon the user actions.

I am very confused sometime the ajax request give server error but why? If it was a syntax  error it should give this error every time. Here is one of the code of the ajax request from my requests

```
@if(Auth::check())
    updateLastActivity();
   @endif
    
    function updateLastActivity(){
         $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            url:'{{route('user.updateLastActivity')}}',
            type:'get',
            success:function(data,status){},
            
                complete:function(data){
             setTimeout(updateLastActivity,5000);
         }
                
                
                });
    }
```

here is the server code behind this request.

```
public function updateLastActivity(){
    $activity=Useractivity::find(session()->get('last_activity_id'));
    $activity->updated_at=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $activity->save();
    return response('success');
}
```

How to resolve that issue.

Comment: It may be that a certain path through your PHP is giving an error, but without the server code it's impossible to tell.

Comment: check the server code, i updated my question.

Comment: check server's error log. there should be complete description with line where error occurred.

Comment: by using this piece of code?
    error:function(error){
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(error));

Comment: `storage/logs/laravel.log` will tell you exactly what the problem is.